# Programmatically convert synchronous code to asynchronous code

Tags: javascript, interpreter, metalanguage

I am writing a parser for a metalanguage to be run in the browser.  The metalanguage is blocking, but needs to be converted to nonblocking in the interpreter due to the limitations of javascript.

For example, the metalanguage code might look something like

```
1. dosomething(4)
2. dosomethingelse(1)
3. dosomething(7)
4. goto 2
```

with the functions implemented in javascript as

```
function dosomething(n, callback) {
  ... // do something with n
  setTimeout(callback, 1000);
}

function dosomethingelse(n, callback) {
  ... // do something else with n
  setTimeout(callback, 1000);
}
```

Without the `goto` statements, this would be easy to compile to javascript and then `eval`.  However, I have no clue how to implement the `goto`s.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: unconditional goto is just a while loop

Comment: how do you interpret a blocking while loop in a nonblocking language?

Comment: I do not understand this question.

Comment: do you want to wait for all your asynchronous `dosomething` calls to complete and then do a goto?

Comment: I want to wait for an entire numbered line to complete before continuing.

Comment: I usually do it using promises. Like https://github.com/kriskowal/q

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising (no pun intended)

Comment: there is another library, Async, that I have never used: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22493723/node-js-asynchronous-library-comparison-q-vs-async?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, check out Promises. This tutorial really helped me out for getting started with them, hopefully it helps you too. https://spring.io/understanding/javascript-promises

Answer (score 1):

Use `yield` to make functions you can pause and then [regenerator](https://facebook.github.io/regenerator/) to run it in older browsers:

First, we convert `dosomething(4)` in your language into:

```
function doSomething(n, callback){
    setTimeout(function(){ callback(null,true); }, n);
}
```

Note the node err-back convention - callbacks take two arguments - the first is an error and the second is the return value.

Then - you can convert them to promises easily:

```
var doSomething = Promise.promisify(doSomething); // using bluebird.
```

Now, when they return promises- you can wrap lines with `yield`s:

```
Promise.coroutine(function*(){ 
    yield dosomething(4);
    yield dosomethingelse(1);
    yield dosomething(7);
});
```

You will need to call [addYieldHandler](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#promisecoroutineaddyieldhandlerfunction-handler---void) in order to deal with yielded non-promise values. This will execute them "synchronously" waiting for each promise to resolve before starting the next. Finally use regenerator to convert your code into something ES5 browsers can run (Since yield only works in FF and in Chrome under a flag atm).